# Magnolia CMS: extend dialog & remove given inherited field

Tags: inheritance, configuration, content-management-system, magnolia

In **Magnolia CMS**, I am [reusing configuration](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Reusing+configuration) by extending a [dialog definition](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Dialog+definition).

However, there is one field I do not want to inherit.

I could image something like adding a node of the same name with a property called "inherit" with value "disable". However, I found nothing under the [common field properties](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Field+definition#Fielddefinition-Commonfieldproperties) available.

Answer (score 3):

If by extending you mean using JCR property `extends=/path/to/some/dialog` then under the node/field that you don't want to have, simply add property `extends` with value set to `override`.
More info in [official documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Configuration+management#Configurationmanagement-Overriding).

Comment: Thx Jan, I appreciate ur quick replies.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution but **a work around**

It is possible to use a [hidden field](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Hidden+field)

**Note**: don't forget to set its `required` property to `false`